# How to change dynamic date format with angular material date picker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular6

[image]
And here is my code that change date format with users choice

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1"  [value]="task_due_date.value" (dateChange)="change_due_date($event)">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please share what "change_due_date()" function does. What have you tried and where you are facing the issue.

Comment: Also, this might be confused if you are in need of a mask, like ngx-mask.

Comment: see in image if i select date from calender then date  should be in "dd-mm-yyyy" format @invoker

Comment: @abhikoshik this is probably what a mask can do! take a look [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

Comment: The requirement is still unclear from your question. But considering your comment and that you just want to change default date format, [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats) is a link which you should go through (if you haven't already).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

{provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_NATIVE_DATE_FORMATS}

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive? Where and how did you use your code?